# Cannot apply individual column searching with Chumper Datatables and Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, datatables, laravel-blade

I am stuck on the following,

I am using Chumper/datatable to display data from a MySQL database using PHP Laravel.

As descriped I have created two routes, One to deliver the view to the user, the other for datatable data:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::get('api/users', array('as'=>'api.users', 'uses'=>'UsersController@getDatatable'));
```

Then the controller

```
public function getDatatable()
{
    return Datatable::collection(User::all(array('id','name', 'address')))
    ->showColumns('id', 'name', 'address')
    ->searchColumns('name')
    ->orderColumns('id','name')
    ->make();
}
```

and in blade page

```
@extends ('layouts.main')

@section('content')
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <div id="User">

  {{ Datatable::table()
     ->addColumn('id', 'name', 'address')
     ->setUrl(route('api.users'))
     ->render() 
  }}

  </div>

@stop
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to apply the individual column searching (select inputs) and search in all 3 columns.

Thank you
/magefi

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, You can pass multiple fields to `searchColumns()`

**Controller:**

```
->searchColumns(array('id:char:255', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'email', 'age:char:255'))
```

**Package:**
Line 237 of `vendor/chumper/datatable/src/Chumper/Datatable/Engines/BaseEngine.php`

```
      237:     public function searchColumns($cols)
      238      {
      239          if ( ! is_array($cols))
                       ....
```

**From README.md:**

> **searchColumns(..$fields)**
>
> Will enable the table to allow search only in the given columns.
>   Please note that a collection behaves different to a builder object.
>
> Note: If you want to search on number columns with the query engine,
>   then you can also pass a search column like this  ```
>       //mysql
>       ->searchColumns(array('id:char:255', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'email', 'age:char:255'))
>
> ````
> //postgree
> ->searchColumns(array('id:text', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'email', 'age:text'))  ```
> ````
>
> This will cast the columns int the given types when searching on this
>   columns

Comment: Thank you c-grifffin. I've changed the ->searchColumns into an array. But in the table output nothing has been changed. I still have only one search field as it is by default in datatables. So I don't have the dropdown menus for each column to search into them.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to implement [link] (http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Comment: Ah, i see...  So, you'll need to pass it a custom javascript view to use instead of the default.  I would copy the default to a new file, make [these modifications](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html), then pass the modified script template to the `table helper` in your data table view `->script('the.new.js.file.you.made')`.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why Chumper package cannot work for me and do the same thing as in the above link (add search to every column mentioned). That way I will avoid the custom javascript view which is really not clear to me.